# How do I migrate Windows 10 and Grub to a new Hard Drive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10, grub

I have two drives: C:, which contains a Grub bootloader and Windows 10, and D: which contains an NTFS partition and also all my Ubuntu partitions. I would like to replace my C: drive with a new (bigger) one, without having to reinstall everything. What do I have to do, in order to not mess up my boot loader?

Comment: There are numerous programs that exist can duplicate a HDD to another HDD.  Which programs have you tested but ruled out?

Comment: AFAIK grub works on a drive ID based System, so when I just clone the drive, I'm afraid Grub won't recognize it anymore.

Comment: Have you ever even tried?  [It isn't difficult to fix an ID problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688634) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/635608/how-to-make-duplicate-of-whole-hdd) and perhaps [this](http://superuser.com/questions/59348/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-a-linux-partition-onto-a-smaller-partition)

Comment: I'd rather inform myself beforehand, rather than breaking my system and then attempting to fix it afterwards.

Comment: You can assign any ID you want to a drive.  The ID is a software ID.  The limitation is that multiple mounted drives, can't have the same ID, for obvious reasons